# SSRS - Linking/Lookup Parameter Labels to return different values?

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, parameters

I'm relatively new to this reporting stuff, so I'm not sure if this will make sense, but here goes...

There are two parameters below (@ComboLL & @ComboMob), both parameters have the same labels but different values per label.

I would like the @ComoboMob parameter to stay hidden from the end user, but I would like their selection of @ComboLL to determine the value used for the @ComboMob parameter.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kcpt7rddqtx990h/Screen.JPG

As both have the same labels is this in any way possible? So if someone selects Pack 1, it will use value 1000 for @ComboLL but value 250 for @ComboMob, for instance.

Or alternatively, is there a less complicated way of doing this that I've missed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay this is tested in 2008 R2 and 2012, I am NOT certain it will work with 2005 but here goes.

Yes you can do this in 2008 and up I am sure.  Set up your first parameter.  Now set up a dataset to be the values of your first Parameter that will get the data for the second.

```
Select Thing
from Table 
where value = @ComboLL
```

Now when you set up a second parameter, make it hidden.

Set the 'Available Values' to 'Get values from a query' choose the dataset similar to above.  Set the 'Default Values' to aslo 'Get values from a query' as well.  This ensure the datasource for the parameter is limited in scope to a single set and a row result for a default.  Ensure you only return a single row.

**Keep in mind to that when you limit parameter scope to a dataset you can choose a different label and value.  This may serve your purposes easier than connecting two parameters if you simply want to label something different than the value you are giving in code.**